# Are commutative matrices closed under matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a set V that contains all matrices that commute with matrix A: AB = BA

How would I go about proving/disproving set V is closed under matrix multiplication?

Comment: If two matrices are in the set, is the product in the set? How would you check this? What equation are you trying to verify?

Comment: Pick any set $D = BC$ with $B,C \in V$. Is it true that $DA = AD$?

Comment: Of course it is.

Comment: It is somewhat difficult to imagine with what exactly you were having problems in trying to prove this! Next time, it would be much better if you told us what you have tried and with what, exactly, you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B,C \in V$. Then:

$$
(BC)A = B(CA)=B(AC)=(BA)C=(AB)C = A(BC)
$$

So $BC$ commutes with $A$, meaning $BC \in V$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\bracks{M,N} \equiv MN - NM}$.

\begin{align}
\bracks{A,BC} & = B\bracks{A,C} + \bracks{A,B}C\implies
\pars{~\bracks{A,C} = \bracks{A,B} = 0\implies
\color{#f00}{\bracks{A,BC}} = \color{#f00}{0}~}
\end{align}

> $\ds{B,C \in V \implies BC \in V}$.